# How to get class object without an instance or class name

Tags: java, class, static

I have an abstract class `MyClass` with a static method to populate given collection with a number of `MyClassDescendant` objects. This method should call a static `getRandom()` method of `MyClassDescendant` to get object instances.

My current code looks like this:

```
public static void populate(Collection<MyClass> coll, Class<? extends MyClass> cl, int num) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Method m;
        m = cl.getMethod("getRandom");
        coll.add((MyClass)(m.invoke(null)));
    }
}
```

Then I call it like that:

```
MyClass.populate((Collection<MyClass>)(Collection<?>)collection, MyClassDescendant.class, 3);
```

This code works, but it's ugly. What I actually wanted to achieve would look like this:

```
MyClassDescendant.populate(collection, 3);
```

If it wasn't a static method, I'd just use `this.getClass()`. I know that `MyClass.class` would work for static method, but I don't want `class` for `MyClass`, but for specific `MyClassDescendant` (there are few descendant types).

Is there any way to get class object without having its instance or class name?

Comment: Since the method `populate()` in the base class is static, it can not be overriden in derived classes. Instead, you can implement it in each derived class to populate the collection with instances of that class.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I'd like to avoid copy-pasting almost identical code across multiple classes.

Comment: Do you always call it in a static context?

Comment: you can't override static methods, you can only hide them ... if you really want to override them you need to make it non-static

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes, it's always called statically.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm not trying to override any static methods here.

Comment: You will either have to duplicate code, or you'll have to supply the Class to the method since the collections does not have any information about the type of its items since generics are implemented by type erasure in Java.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I know about type erasure, but don't understand how does it apply here? The new elements' class won't depend on what's already in the collection. My point is to call `MyClassDescendant`'s method instead of passing `MyClassDescendant` as an argument to the `MyClass`'s method. I'm looking for something like `this.getClass()`, but for use with static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a static context you'll have to duplicate some code, but you can do delegation.

```
public class MyClassDescendant extends MyClass {
    public static void populate(Collection<MyClass> coll, int count) {
        MyClass.populate(coll, MyClassDescendant.class, count);
    }
}
```

Now you can call
`MyClassDescendant.populate(collection, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

If get random is a static method couldn't you just call it?

```
public interface MyClassInterface { 
    MyClass getRandom();
}

public abstract class MyClass implements MyClassInterface {
    public static void populate(Collection<MyClass> coll, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {            
            coll.add((MyClass)MyClassDescendant.getRandom());
        }
    }
}

public class MyClassDescendant extends MyClass {
    public MyClass getRandom() {
        // implementation of getRandom
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyClassDescendant` isn't the only descendant, there are few types of those. A static abstract method `getRandom()` in `MyClass` would solve the problem (I think), but Java doesn't allow static abstract methods.

Comment: If want multiple children that each have a getRandom method you should create an interface and let MyClass implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your method in this way:

```
public static <T extends Base> void populate(Collection<T> coll, int num) throws Exception{
    for (T item : coll) {
        Method m;
        m = item.getClass().getMethod("getRandom");
        coll.add((T)(m.invoke(null)));
    }
}
```

With regards to one the comments, you can also use the [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern to utilize inheritance for your `getRandom()` method by making it abstract and calling it within your populate method.

Comment: You'll run into a concurrent modification exception since you are modifying the collection you are currently iterating over. Furthermore if the collections is empty this will never call getRandom.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings that completely depends on what kind of `Collection` is being passed in. Your second comment is correct it seems like that is intended functionality.

Comment: If I understand what you did there, this method will iterate over each element in the collection and create a new random instance of its class. This is not what I want to do. The collection should hold *multiple* types of `MyClass` descendants and `populate()` should add *a number* of specific class' instances.

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you for clearing up what you are expecting out of this method.